# Can a class that has only one public void method be called 'service'?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm writing implementations of a specific *Validator* interface. It is designed in a way that it is expected to throw a specific exception when the validation fails. I have no possibility to change this design.

Each implementation obtains validation input from the input data set in a different way and validates different number of data sets. However for each validation input the actual validation code is the same.
That's why I decided to write a class with *validate* method to place this common code and call it from each *Validator* implementation whenever needed.
The class is something like this:

```
public class SpecificValidationService {

    public void validate (Condition condition1, Condition condition2) {
        if (conditionNotMet(condition1, condition2)) {
            throw new SpecificException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that having a service that has only one public method (that is void) seems wrong to me. Generally I would expect a service to have a few methods that are not void.
Am I right here? What should be a better name? Remember that I cannot use 'validator' as it can be confused with the *Validator* implementations. Or maybe my approach is wrong altogether?

Comment: Normally `Service` is a place for business logic. So Validator would be better. Maybe find a Synonym for Validator? Like, Verification..Dude :) Acceptance..something..

Comment: IMO what you are aiming for is an utility class. Like, if you are validating cars, put this method in CarUtils.java. I'd say it isn't a service indeed, but not because of the number of methods or the return types (this shouldn't affect at all if your class is a service or not), but because this class isn't providing logic regarding what you have to do with your cars in your application (business logic).

Comment: @raviiii1 Thanks. If you want to please write an answer based on your comment and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Thanks. I am glad it helped. I added the comment as answer and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concrete definition of a service class. Infact a service can mean different thing in different languages/frameworks. In Java, generally any class that implements some Business logic can be called a service. There is nothing wrong with a service with a single void function. However the SpecificValidationService class looks to me more like a utility class and can be kept in service layer. You may call it SpecificValidationUtility in that case.

I would like to share this answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/343213 for an explaination on service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first clarify that there is absolutely nothing wrong with `void` methods and there is absolutely nothing wrong with classes only having `void` methods by themselves.

The very question of whether classes having only `void` methods should be avoided is wrongly put. The question you should ask yourself about a plan of yours, or a `class` of yours looks like this:

**Is this class meeting my requirements?**

If the answer is yes, then it is not interesting whether it only has a `void` method or not. If the answer is no, you will need to ask yourself the next question:

**How would this class look alike if it was meeting my requirements and what is the difference between what it should be like and what it is?**

And since you are asking now the good questions, you will have a higher chance of finding the good answers.

I understand that you need an `interface` for your validation and you want to implement at least a method. This means that you need an `abstract class` to `implement` your `interface`.

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator implements Validator {
    public void validate (Condition condition1, Condition condition2) {
        if (conditionNotMet(condition1, condition2)) {
            throw new SpecificException();
        }
    }
}
```

and then for each specific validator, inherit from `AbstractValidator`. Also, document at `Validator` that it is not meant to be implemented by anything else than `AbstractValidator`, so other people, who might find your `interface` will not make the mistake of implementing it separately.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: Thanks, but you completely misunderstood my question. I never wrong that a void methods are wrong per se. I'm also not looking for a new interface.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong I have not suggested to you to implement a new interface. I suggested that you should implement your interface which already exists with an abstract class, since that is the elegant way to achieve what you described you need. Please, read the answer again.

Comment: That's not achievable. I guess I would need to provide more code/explanation to explain why, but I don't have time for it at the moment.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong you are telling me it is impossible to implement your validate method in an abstract class which implements the interface from your question? I am very curious to know why it is not achievable in your case.

Comment: Sorry, my bad here. Just by coincidence the Validator interface main method is also called validate (which of course you couldn't know) and that's what confused me and I misunderstood your answer. Your suggestion is obviously correct. In fact my code was written exactly like this yesterday. However I've consulted it with my colleague and we decided that it's not a good way to go here because duplication of some code (not being part of this question) is unavoidable and we both prefer composition over inheritance. One again though: just based on the details I provided your suggestion is proper.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong no problem, you might want to accept this answer as the correct one, or write your own answer and accept it. In the latter case you will need to add some more details to the question though.